# What is wrong with my timestamps?

Tags: php, mysql, unix, timezone, timestamp

So basicly, I played around with my MySQL database a couple of days ago and I set the timezone to MST to match with the server I have my PHP-script on (I've also set the PHP-server timezone to MST (`date_default_timezone_set("MST")`) to match with the database). I have a function which requires one parameter and that's an UNIX timestamp.

```
function time_elapsed_string($time)
{
    $time = time() - $time;

    $tokens = array(
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );

    foreach($tokens as $unit => $text)
    {
        if($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }
}
```

What this function does is that it takes the `$time`. It gets the time difference between the current time and the $time and sets `$time` to the difference. It then calculates the biggest possible timestamp the `$time` could be and echoes it. If it's in plural (2 weeks, 5 months etc) it adds a *s* to the end.

However, if I put the current time as the `$time`-parameter it'll echo '**[SPACE]ago**'. I've solved that temporarily by replacing the row `$time = time() - $time;` with `$time = (time() + 80) - $time;` where I increase the current number *80* with 5 or 10 to make it accurate.

**Short explanation:**
I have to add seconds to the current time when calculating the difference to make so that it doesn't echo just '**[SPACE]ago**'.

I'm using this function when I've updated my status on my page, an insert-query gets sent to the database (without the time-column filled) and because the timestamp column is the current timestamp on default it gets set to the current timestamp.

How can I fix this because I really understand that adding 5 or 10 everyday won't be stable in the future.

PS. I don't think I can restart my MySQL server or such because I'm on a webhost and I guess I don't have the right privileges to do so.

**EDIT1:**
It looks like the inserted timestamp is around 1 minute ahead then it is in real life. Could this be causing it?

**EDIT2:**
Now, a couple of weeks later I need to add between 100 & 200 seconds extra to make sure the *time ago* function is accurate.

Comment: What is wrong with [PHP date_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) or [MySQL datediff()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Comment: Looks like it doesn't support UNIX tiemstamps. What I want to get returned is the difference in seconds. @Anigel

Comment: Use date() or from_unixtime() to sort that out.

Comment: It does not look like it solved it, thanks for your reply though. I guess it has something to do with the timezones. @Anigel

Comment: Thats why I suggested date_diff as it is timezone aware. Is the time on your server right?

Comment: It's not, therefore I used the date_default_timezone_set("MST") function on top of all of my pages. Be sure to check **EDIT1** in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing the difference based on what is stored in MySQL, your choices are:

1. Use Network Time Protocol (see http://pool.ntp.org/) across your servers, and hope for the best...
2. Or fetch the time from MySQL using [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) in options like below:

   - within your query: `SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS unix_timestamp FROM table`
   - or call it separately: `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS unix_timestamp`

An optional second parameter is the secret which can help by passing in the "unix_timestamp" result from MySQL into the second optional parameter, coding an optimized difference (you found 5 to 10 'working'), or simply allow the PHP timestamp() function to become the default as already implemented above when your servers get synchronized.

Either way make a simple update to the function like this:

```
function time_elapsed_string($time, $time0 = NULL)
{
    if ($time0 === NULL) 
    {
        $time0 = time();
    }
    $time = $time0 - $time;
    ...
```

EXAMPLE uses:

```
time_elapsed_string($recordTimeStamp);                         // as-is
time_elapsed_string($recordTimeStamp, time() + 5);             // an "optimized" difference
time_elapsed_string($recordTimeStamp, $recordUnixTimeStamp);   // from MySQL addition
time_elapsed_string($recordTimeStamp, $databaseUnixTimeStamp); // from separate query
```

Comment: This pretty much fixed it. Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 1):

What isn't clear to me is *how* you're storing your timestamp in MySQL. There are at least three ways to store a date in MySQL:

1. As an int - output from time()
2. As `DATETIME`
3. As `TIMESTAMP`

The first two options don't even take into account the timezone of the database server. You don't even really say how you set the timezone either.

Assuming for the moment you're using a `TIMESTAMP`, you can get a unix timestamp from MySQL using the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function.

When setting the timezone setting on the MySQL server, it's usually better to do it on a per-session basis, like this:

```
$sql = "SET names $charset, time_zone='".date("P")."'";
```

The root of your problem seems to be the function itself. There are not exactly "31536000" seconds in each year, nor are there "2592000" seconds in a month. This is because of there being different amount of days in a month, leap-years, etc.

This is based on a function I wrote a long time ago (rewrote it to make it easier to read). Hopefully it'll be useful to you:

```
function relativeTime($time)
{
    $date = getdate($time);
    $today = getdate();
    $daydiff = $today["mday"]-$date["mday"];
    $text = "";

    if ($today["mon"] === $date["mon"] && $today["year"] === $date["year"] && $daydiff < 2) {
        if ($daydiff === 1) {
            $text =  sprintf('Yesterday, %s', date('g:i A T', $time));
        } else if ($today["hours"] == $date["hours"]) {
            $min = $today["minutes"] - $date["minutes"];
            if ($min > 1) {
                $text = sprintf('%s minutes ago', $min);
            } else {
                $text = 'A minute ago';
            }
        } else {
            $text = sprintf('Today, %s', date('g:i A T', $time));
        }
    } else {
        $text = date('j F Y - g:i A T', $time);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

The function above only does "# minutes ago" and "Today", "Yesterday", and then the date. You can, of course, add to it to make it be even more precise.

Comment: I have a field in the table with the type set as a *TIMESTAMP* with the default value as the *CURRENT_TIMESTAMP*. Your function looks good but I don't think it's any problem with my function. The problem seems to occur when inserting a row into the database. The timestamp then gets set to a future time (currently around 150 ahead of the current time). That must have something to do with the timezones between the database server and the php server.

I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: @MagnusBurton Then the date must be out of sync on the database server. You can always insert a value from time() instead. Still, your function uses fixed time for months, and you'll end up with errors when there can be 28, 29, 30, or 31 days in a month.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the MySQL `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` when you insert your data, if use php to calculate it from time() they will match and you will not have the post time 60 seconds ahead of now. You could always use time()-1 when you insert that way there will always be at least 1 second difference.

To get a mysql DATETIME format from date just use this, then specify the value for your column as $date.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time()-1));
```

In most hosting environments the sql server and web servers are different servers so there can be some time drift between them, but it certainly shouldn't be in the order of a minute, any web host worth their salt will ensure they are all synced with the same time server so any drift should be measured in microseconds

Answer (score 0):

The problem you were having was because if $time was less than 1 then there wasn't any lesser denomination for it.

I fixed it with an if statement and also renamed a variable

```
function time_elapsed_string($time)
{
    $time_diff = time() - $time;

    $tokens = array(
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second',
    );

    if ($time_diff < 1)
        return '0 seconds';

    foreach($tokens as $unit => $text)
    {
        if($time_diff < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time_diff / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
    }
}
```

You can also use the following, verbatim from the PHP docs:
Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Two quick approaches to getting the time elapsed in human readable form.

```
function time_elapsed_A($secs){
    $bit = array(
        'y' => $secs / 31556926 % 12,
        'w' => $secs / 604800 % 52,
        'd' => $secs / 86400 % 7,
        'h' => $secs / 3600 % 24,
        'm' => $secs / 60 % 60,
        's' => $secs % 60
        );

    foreach($bit as $k => $v)
        if($v > 0)$ret[] = $v . $k;

    return join(' ', $ret);
    }


function time_elapsed_B($secs){
    $bit = array(
        ' year'        => $secs / 31556926 % 12,
        ' week'        => $secs / 604800 % 52,
        ' day'        => $secs / 86400 % 7,
        ' hour'        => $secs / 3600 % 24,
        ' minute'    => $secs / 60 % 60,
        ' second'    => $secs % 60
        );

    foreach($bit as $k => $v){
        if($v > 1)$ret[] = $v . $k . 's';
        if($v == 1)$ret[] = $v . $k;
        }
    array_splice($ret, count($ret)-1, 0, 'and');
    $ret[] = 'ago.';

    return join(' ', $ret);
    }




$nowtime = time();
$oldtime = 1335939007;

echo "time_elapsed_A: ".time_elapsed_A($nowtime-$oldtime)."\n";
echo "time_elapsed_B: ".time_elapsed_B($nowtime-$oldtime)."\n";

/** Output:
time_elapsed_A: 6d 15h 48m 19s
time_elapsed_B: 6 days 15 hours 48 minutes and 19 seconds ago.
**/
```

Comment: I don't think you've understood my problem or I may have not made myself clear enough, sorry! I need a way to synchronize the PHP server and the MySQL server down to the seconds as they're currently different from each other with around 2 minutes. When inserting a new record to the database the time gets set to the future compared to the PHP server. Thank you for your functions though!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

" However, if I put the current time as the $time-parameter it'll echo '[SPACE]ago'. "

So in this case your $time param going to be equal to time().
In your function body this line:

```
$time = time() - $time;
```

actually going to be $time = time() - time();
Which is 0 because 1sec wont elapse between the two time() calls (usually).

I think is better if you use the php DateTime object.

```
$now = new DateTime();

$timeObject = new DateTime();
$timeObject->setTimestamp($time);

// DateInterval object created by DateTime::diff()
$diff = $now->diff($timeObject);

// Number of years.
echo $diff->y;

// Number of months.
echo $diff->m;

// Number of days.
echo $diff->d;

// Number of hours.
echo $diff->h;

// Number of minutes.
echo $diff->i;

// Number of seconds.
echo $diff->s;
```